# Execute SQL command with parameter using Devart EF Drivers for Oracle

Tags: .net, oracle, devart

I am trying to delete records from an Oracle table before inserting new ones using a sql command and a parameter because the value comes from the browser.

This is the code:

```
var tableName = "<myTableName>";
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE :p0", tableName);
```

Oracle is throwing "ORA-00903: invalid table name".

I have also tried:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE :p0", new OracleParameter("p0", OracleDbType.VarChar, 200, tableName, ParameterDirection.Input)
```

Is there something simple I am missing?

Comment: Parameters cannot be used to specify table or column names. By the way the SQL syntax is DELETE FROM _tablename_

Comment: ok, so how do I do this to prevent SQL injection? DELETE <tablename> works in SqlDeveloper

Comment: You don't let your user type the table name. You need to present a list of tables and let him/her select the table name

Comment: yup - that's what I do but those table names are passed back in string format. a hacker could change those string values. sounds like I need to add some extra validation based on a list of valid table names. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bounce the table against `ALL_TABLES` you should be able to prevent any SQL Injection attacks:

```
private bool TruncateTable(string Schema, string Table)
{
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select count (*) from all_tables " +
        "where owner = :SCHEMANAME and table_name = :TABLENAME", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("SCHEMANAME", Schema.ToUpper());
    cmd.Parameters.Add("TABLENAME", Table.ToUpper());

    if (Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) == 0)
        return false;

    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("delete from {0}.{1}", Schema, Table);
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return true;
}
```

On DevArt, I think the `Add` would instead be `AddWithValues` but would otherwise look the same.

In this case, a return value of false meant there was no such table.  This all presupposes the user has the ability to delete from the table in question.

Also, if possible, a `truncate` is a nice alternative to a `delete from`.  It's quite a bit faster and resets the high water mark.  I think you need to be an owner or have the "drop any table" privilege to do this, but there are other ways around it -- for example, have the DBA set up a stored procedure to do the truncation on certain tables.

Comment: Cheers. That's a good way of avoiding injection. I was actually using EF so I used reflection to make sure the table existed in the edmx model :)